# How to configure Jenkins authentication with Google apps

Tags: authentication, jenkins, google-apps, jenkins-plugins

I had installed Jenkins in ubuntu 12.04 and it is running successfully. Other users are trying to login my Jenkins, so, i feel it would be if it get configured with Google apps. let me know the way to configure Jenkins with Google apps.

Answer (score 0):

Setup is really quite easy.  First of course need to install the plugin.  Once you have done this just go to "Manage Jenkins" and then select "Configure Global Security".  Once you are here just select "Google Apps SSO (with OpenID)" under the Security Realm section and then put your google apps domain.  Next step profit and of course :)

-John

Comment: may i know the name of plugin, which needs to be installed

Comment: Hahahaaahh :) Open-ID plugin